# SVMs for nested/prioritzed text document classes.

Tags: svm, nested-data, e1071

Let's say A, B, C, D, E, F are classes of text documents (i.e. sentences). Usually they occur distinctively, say: one document is precisely C. But sometimes one document is C AND A, at the same time. Because A is more important than C, the document class is defined . So at least two questions arise:

*1) How this classification would be made properly with an SVM?*

*2) Is this possible in R?*

Note: I already tried to do this with the standard approach (linear classification, 10000 features, e1071 SVM implementation). The classes distribution isn't constant (F is much more frequent than A, B, or C). Sadly here the most most important classes (A, B, C) are wrongly classified as F.

*3) Is there a possibility to set a priority for an standard SVM?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign class-weights in e1071 using `class.weights`. This would help solve your problem, by assigning higher weights to the important classes `A`, `B` and `C`.

In this approach you basically split the global misclassification penalty $C$ per class. For a binary problem you solve an optimization problem with the following objective function (generalization to multiclass is trivial):

$$
\min_{\mathbf{w},\xi} \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{w}\|^2 + C_{\mathcal{P}} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{P}} \xi_i  + C_{\mathcal{N}} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{N}} \xi_i,
$$
where $\mathbf{w}$ is the separating hyperplane, $\xi$ the slack variables and $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ represent the positive and negative set, respectively. This is a very common way to deal with imbalanced problems, e.g. when some classes occur much less often than others. A commonly used guesstimate for the ratio $C_{\mathcal{P}}/C_{\mathcal{N}}$ is the following:
$$
C_{\mathcal{P}} \times |\mathcal{P}| = C_{\mathcal{N}} \times |\mathcal{N}|,
$$
with $|\mathcal{P}|$ and $|\mathcal{N}|$ the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{N}$, respectively. This ratio equalizes the total misclassification penalty on $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: Thank You! Really nice :) So do I understand you well? I may use the weights for two purposes (1) for class imbalance and (2) importance level. Because I experimented very early with weights (at the time I used Gaussian kernel) the results got worse. However, I had no real clue how to balance them. I'll try your proposal and come back tomorrow :)

Comment: @alex yes, that is correct.